# GraphQL type query: Getting error "Expected Name, found String 'type'"

Tags: graphql, hasura

I am trying to create a object relationship using Hasura GraphQL API. Followed the documentation https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/api-reference/schema-metadata-api/relationship.html#create-object-relationship. This is what I did.

```
{
  "type": "create_object_relationship",
    "args": {
        "table": "article",
        "name": "article_detail",
        "using": {
            "manual_configuration" : {
                "remote_table" : "article_detail",
                "column_mapping" : {
                    "id" : "article_id"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting syntax error **"Expected Name, found String 'type'"**

Need help what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? When you query your server? If so, then it sounds like an issue with your query.

Comment: yeah. I understand that query is wrong. But I copied it from documentation. and error is in 2nd line under keyword 'type'